# Sort by percent of row values in a pivot table - google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I want to be able to be sort by the percent of row values inside of a pivot table in google sheets. Here I have an example spreadsheet that keeps track of the type of game played (A, B, or C), their result (Win or Loss), and a pivot table.

[Here is the link to the spreadsheet:](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mfI2mBFzIqNP9ZQFQioAurnAN8Xaj9XFMGQL8hMavY8/edit#gid=0)

Picture of the pivot table:

[image]

In the values field, I added a COUNTA function from the Result column, and it shows the total number of wins and losses for each game. I added another COUNTA function from the Result column, but this time it shows the values as a percentage of the total of the row total, which becomes the win/loss percentage for each game.

I can choose to sort either of these columns in the pivot table editor, but they both sort by the original COUNTA value, not the % of row value, so it will only sort by total wins/total losses for each game instead of winning percentage.

Does anyone know a way to sort how I want to? Or do I have to edit my source data?

I have tried to use calculated fields, but they don't seem to be the right tool for what I need to do. I don't seem to be available to all of the information I need.

Like I said before, I tried conventional sorting in the pivot table editor, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: `Does anyone know a way to sort how I want to` Would you please edit your question to include an example of how you want the pivot table to sort. You'll have to do it manually but it should be possible to produce something that displays the outcome that you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

A pivot table shows total wins/total losses for each game. But the pivot table should also show the `winning percentage`.

`Results` Column values were originally created:

- `COUNTA - default`
- `COUNTA - % of row`

Both of these are row-oriented; in order to show the "winning percentage" two things are required:

1. `COUNTA - % of column`
2. Sort `GAME` by `% of column - Win`

---

**Pivot Editor**

### [image: editor]

**Winning Percentage**

[image: winning percentage]